# How to get joomla version by http?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, joomla-1.5

I have seen screenshots of a solution, there the Joomla version is getting detected by only accessing the page via http.

E.g. the solution displayed all 3 digits of a version of Joomla. e.g. 2.5.28, or 1.0.x and so on by only accessing the webpage via http.

I want to create a small application to be informed about the version installed on the server. Since I do not have always full access to the FTP storage, I would like to know how I can extract the Joomla version from a simple HTTP GET.

Comment: Are you referring to your own website or an external website. If external, then this cannot be done

Comment: Visit [joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/182/how-can-i-programatically-determine-the-joomla-version-of-a-website-on-which-i-h](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/182/how-can-i-programatically-determine-the-joomla-version-of-a-website-on-which-i-h) and see the answer of @BrianPeat.

Comment: @Farahmand - The links provided won't be any help for the exact version, such as **2.5.28**. Only main version numbers such as **1.5** and **2.5**

Comment: @Lodder - Please check this link: [whitefirdesign.com/tools/joomla-version-check.html](http://www.whitefirdesign.com/tools/joomla-version-check.html) that shows the exact version.

Comment: @Lodder - I checked the link and it works for Joomla 2.5 versions but doesn't work for some Joomla 3 versions.

Comment: @Farahmand - some 3.x versions work. With some of them, it will only display `3.3.x`. I've been looking through a load of JS script on Joomla to see if they have placed the version anywhere but they haven't :/ cause then it would be easy to parse

Comment: Just open `www.yourdomain.com/administrator/manifests/files/joomla.xml`

Comment: Only files you can reasonably guarantee to have access remotely via HTTP are css, javascript, image, and font files in media and templates folders that are parts of the default install. You can check which of these have changed in various versions and then compare to what the server returns.

Comment: @NilsRückmann - You can't do this

Comment: @Lodder of course, you can. On every standard installation.

Comment: @Farahmand: the link you provided is the screenshot I have got. Thank you.
Still it is not clear for me how the version is detected. Whitefiredesign seems (from apache logs) only access the toplevel page, no other accesses are in the logs.

Comment: @Nils, the link only works for 2.5+ and it is not clear if you have always access to the file.

Comment: @NilsRückmann - It will be very rare that this file is accessible. I have tried on multiple Joomla sites on different servers using Joomla 2.5 and 3.x, and none of them work. They all redirect to `mod_secure.html` which is a restricted access page. There's a reason why the Joomla version isn't easy to detect. My first guess would be for security reasons.

Comment: I've written a function that will get all exact versions for the 2.5 series (2.5.4, 2.5.26 etc) and the minor versions for the 3.x series.

Comment: @Lodder it seems you have more advanced joomla users in uk ;). Just try those: http://community.joomla.org/showcase/sites/new.html. To be clear: I'm not a fan of this, and I'm truly frustrated that standard joomla installations are so unsecure.

Comment: @Lodder, could you share your knowledge as an answer regarding your solution how you extract the versions?

Comment: if @Valentin Despa or another moderator can re-open this question, I will be more than happy to add my code

Comment: FYI: just signed up for joomla.com. http://nueckman.joomla.com/administrator/manifests/files/joomla.xml

Comment: Made a small module out of it my script: http://joomjunk.co.uk/extras-page/joomla-version-detect.html

Comment: @Lodder - maybe it is time to transform your helpful comment into an answer.

Comment: @miroxlav - see below

Comment: @Lodder - Why doesn't your module detect the version of `beytoote.com`? [It's 2.5.x](http://www.whitefirdesign.com/tools/joomla-version-check.html?address=beytoote.com). Maybe it needs a small amendment.

Comment: Maybe, I will look later

Answer (score 16):

Ok so this is what I was writing yesterday.

#### For Joomla 2.5 and 3.x only

1. Check if the `http://` prefix is missing from the URL. If it is, then it adds it. Note that In this case I have **not** taken `https://` into consideration.
2. It then tries to get the Joomla manifest file and checks whether is exists/is readable.
3. If it exists then it gets the value from the `<version>` tag.
4. If the XML file is not readable, then I have written a fallback to get the TinyMCE version. Again, it will try to read the value from the `<version>` tag.
5. From here on, I spent quite a long time going through the release notes for each Joomla version to see which versions has a TinyMCE update. Those that did, I added to the `switch` block further own in the code. This approach will not give the exact version apart from 2 of them, but it will give an average. I was thinking about detecting the jQuery version but then realised that a lot of people update the core version to the latest which would then make the results inaccurate.
6. If the TinyMCE version cannot be found (so basically a non-Joomla site), then the function will return `Unknown`.

**Note:** This script uses `CURL` so make sure it's enabled on your server.

---

```
class JoomlaVersions
{
    public function getJoomlaVersion($site)
    {
        // Add http prefix if missing
        if (strpos($site,'http://') === false)
        {
            $site = 'http://'.$site;
        }
    
        // Get the number value from the <version> tag in the XML file
        $dom = new DOMDocument;
        $url = $site . '/administrator/manifests/files/joomla.xml';
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

        $exists = $this->XMLexists($url);
    
        if( $exists )
        {
            $dom->load($url);
            $versions = $dom->getElementsByTagName('version');
    
            foreach ($versions as $version) 
            {
                return $version->nodeValue;
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            $mce = $this->getTinyMCEversion($site);
    
            if($mce)
            {
                // Base Joomla version on the TinyMCE version
                switch ($mce)
                {
                    case '3.5.6':
                        $joomla = '3.0.0 - 3.1.6';
                        break;
                    case '4.0.10':
                        $joomla = '3.2.0 - 3.2.1';
                        break;
                    case '4.0.12':
                        $joomla = '3.2.2';
                        break;
                    case '4.0.18':
                        $joomla = '3.2.3 - 3.2.4';
                        break;
                    case '4.0.22':
                        $joomla = '3.3.0';
                        break;
                    case '4.0.28':
                        $joomla = '3.3.1 - 3.3.6';
                        break; 
                    case '4.1.7':
                        $joomla = '3.4.0';
                        break; 
                    default:
                        $joomla = '3.x';
                }
    
                return $joomla;
            }
            else 
            {
                return 'Unknown';
            }
        }   
    }

    // Get TinyMCE Version 
    private function getTinyMCEversion($site)
    {
        $tinymce = $site . '/plugins/editors/tinymce/tinymce.xml';      
        libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

        $exists = $this->XMLexists($tinymce);

        if( $exists )
        {
            $dom->load($tinymce);
            $vTag = $dom->getElementsByTagName('version');

            foreach ($vTag as $tag) 
            {
                return $tag->nodeValue;
            }
        }
    }

    // Check file exists using CURL
    private function XMLexists($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
        curl_exec($ch);
        $getinfo = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        curl_close($ch);

        return $getinfo;
    }

}
```

Then call the function like so:

```
$version = new JoomlaVersions;
echo $version->getJoomlaVersion('http://joomla.org');
```

I've created a module on my website as a Tool for other users:

[Joomla Version Detection Tool](http://joomjunk.co.uk/extras-page/joomla-version-detect.html)

I've also created a Github repository if you wish to fork it or submit pull requests:

[Joomla Version Detect Github Repo](https://github.com/C-Lodder/joomla-version-detect)

Anyway, as some of you know, I'm not a backend developer so there are probably a lot of improvements which can be made to the code. If you have another solution or can update what I currently have, be sure to post it as a new answer.

Comment: great solution! Anyway it implies, that you have access to the /administrator/manifests/files/joomla.xml file. So this is not always the case. The other mentioned page has a solution, which detects the version only on the GET of the / page. So it is fully unclear how this is done. The apache logs tell only a simple get to / of the domain, nothing more.

Comment: I've added a Github repository link to the answer.

Comment: Excellent answer which also helps answer the question I asked at http://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/182/120

Comment: **@Joomjunk** I tried the script on your site to check several Joomla sites. Not working. The response is empty.

Comment: @Marc - Some sites work, others won't due to the host not allowing read permissions for certain XML files which is how my the version detection works. There is another site that uses different methods for detecting the version, however I'm unsure as to how they do this. If I can figure out a more appropriate way of doing this, I will implement it.

Comment: I use a similar system and I thought I would add that the cURL response will be: 400 = not found or 200 = found so it's a good idea to have your exists check do something like: if($exists === '200') {

Answer (score 3):

If you are interested only in versions of sites ***you manage***, then you can create and install a small plugin which shares Joomla version by opening plugin URL, for example
`http://example.com/plugins/getversion/getversion.php?configuredSecret`

- I did not need it yet so I don't have the code. But based on [Lodder's answer](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/7187/324), you can see how to read *Joomla!* mainfest file `/administrator/manifests/files/joomla.xml` in order to return the version number.

Note mostly for newbies: `configuredSecret` is one of classical approaches to share publicly visible channel only to authorized requests. It is commonly used for connecting two systems if there is no better way to protect integrating connection.

Comment: administrator/manifests/files/joomla.xml is the answer, for joomla 2.5 at least

Comment: @Lynob – sure. In this case, the OP would like to have lightweight application which receives only single number, not entire XML file. So your solution is suitable for fat client, my solution for thin client.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add this as a separate answer, as it's not exactly a code solution.

I've developed a Firefox extension that performs 2 XHR requests. The first one to the Joomla API site to get the latest version, the other to the `joomla.xml` file of the current website you're viewing. It will then compare the two versions and `console.log()` the result.

URL: https://github.com/C-Lodder/joomla-update-checker