# How to check Joomla version if I've no accessed to the backend?

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5

If I stumble upon a Joomla website ( which I have no access to either the server code, nor the admin backend), can I tell what version of Joomla it's on?

I read [a comment](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/7148/how-to-get-joomla-version-by-http#comment11104_7148) to [this question](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/7148/5735), which says that

> Are you referring to your own website or an external website. If
>   external, then this cannot be done

But on the other hand, I also encounter a [Google Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/version-check-for-joomla/nfbncfldblphagigkamkhnjnhjkdlnii?hl=en) that allows one to determine the Joomla version of any external Joomla website. So I think this is not impossible.

So can it be done by just accessing the HTML, JS, CSS files of the website and all of the tools that are available to a normal but internet savvy user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My initial comment about not being able to get the version from an external website is invalid.

I then went on to write a script which does exactly this which I added as an answer.

The online tool:

https://joomjunk.co.uk/extras-page/joomla-version-detect.html

The script:

https://github.com/C-Lodder/joomla-version-detect

HTML, JS and CSS file will not provide the Joomla version. You have to access an XML file.

Some servers block access to the `manifest.xml` file to prevent gaining information such as the version, which I why I added a fallback, which gets the version of TinyMCE, which I then used to detect the Joomla version

Comment: I can't find anyway I can input the URL at your online tool link, are you sure you put in the right online tool link?

Comment: @Graviton - Oops, sorry: https://joomjunk.co.uk/extras-page/joomla-version-detect.html